# Materialized View Query Rewrite Usage?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

So I have been working with Oracle support over an Materialized view compile issue with our dataguard standby database and they recommended turning off query rewrite (setting `query_rewrite_enabled=false`). We have many MV's that have "enable query rewrite" in them, so I am a little hesitant to turn it off and cause potential performance problems..

Is there any way to tell if the MV's are in fact using query rewrite (perhaps a V$ view or something?)? When I tested querying one of the base tables it did not use the materialized view and an explain plan showed a full table scan. I am thinking that most our the queries wouldn't be rewritten, but I wanted to be sure before making a change.

Also, are there any other big impacts I should be aware off if I turn off `query_rewrite_enabled`?

Comment: I've read the question 4-5 times, but I still can't get what is your problem. Please, shorten and simplify it somehow.

Comment: Does [all_rewrite_equivalences](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-AFE4BD66-B8F5-448C-A0E5-FCE2D85E4F3E.htm#REFRN20344) show you anything useful? You probably can't tell anything about queries that haven't yet been parsed and executed though. And [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/qradv.htm#DWHSG0805) might be useful to investigate the query you tried. I woudl think your Oracle support contact would be able to give some tips though, and explain the impacts?

Comment: Are they recommending this as a permanent change, or only to assist them in troubleshooting, diagnosing and fixing your current problem? I would be quite skeptical of setting `query_rewrite_enabled=false` permanently, exactly for the reasons you shared. Why do they want to do that globally, and not simply `disable query rewrite` on the one MV with compilation problems?

Comment: Sorry the delay, other things came up and I was waiting for responses from support. Thanks for the tips everyone, I will try testing some of our queries and check all_rewrite_equivalences. It looks like we may have a bug, and that disabling query rewrite permanently on the standby database is their recommendation. What is weird is that the MV that is having compilation problems already has query rewrite disabled on it, so I'm thinking a rewrite plan is referencing a different MV than the one that is having the compilation problems.